# Use setFilterModel() on a single ag-grid column?

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, ag-grid

I am trying to clear a single column's filter if it gets hidden. I currently have setFilterModel(null), but it is clearing all of the columns when this particular column gets hidden and the table sets the data again. Is there a way to use setFilterModel() and specify a certain column to clear?

Answer (score 0):

Found in the docs that I could use the grid API's destroyFilter() and pass in the column ID